# Does ACCESS keep internals of who changed what when?

Tags: ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

It is great that multiple concurrent users can make changes to an Access database at the same time.

Is Aceess itself keeping track of who made what changes, when?

i.e.  if one user is logged in with User Authentication as user "Bob", and another user is "Fred", will there be a way to find out if it was Bob or Fred that made a certain change to the database?

Does each change to the Access database get a timestamp of when it occured?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no.  Access does not keep an audit of who changed what or when.  It also lacks any system (like triggers) that would enable you to keep these logs reliably.  Instead, the best you can do is code your application to write necessary audit information to a seperate table but users will be able to bypass it with a little know how.  You'll also need to correctly setup access / jet security to prevent users from being able to modify the audit table.